# How is unit classification created in som, using kohonen package in R

Tags: r, neural-network, som, self-organizing-maps

Code used:

```
system.time(som_model <- som(train_matrix, 
                         grid=som_grid, 
                         rlen= p, 
                         alpha=c(0.05,0.001), 
                         n.hood = "circular",
                         keep.data = TRUE ))
```

By my understanding, `som_model$unit.classif` maps the indices of the winning neurons/BMU's to individual rows of the input data set.
Tried linking them with the final codebook /weighted vectors (`som_model$codes`) but have not been able to establish a link.

Kindly guide me on what basis/rule or formula does the `som` assign these indices to the data.

Comment: Please compare the dimensions of `som_model$codes` and the values in `som_model$unit.classif`. You can `table(som_model$unit.classif)` or `unique(som_model$unit.classif)`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Pascal. I have already done that. My purpose is different. I intend to establish the exact functional form relating the 'som_model$classif' to each observation of the input data set 'train_matrix'. Let me try to explain it better with an example. Suppose we consider a grid of 10X10. The dimension for 'som_model$codes' would be 100. These 100 prototype vectors are then mapped using the algorithm to each element of the input data set train_matrix. Objective is to find why or how did say, train_matrix[2,3] get mapped to say 32 (as it is shown by 'som_model$unit.classif'.

Comment: Are you speaking about the SOM algorithm itself?

Comment: In a way, but not the main part where the neurons are being trained. Instead, how are they mapped using finally trained weights . I'd figure this should not be too much in the black box part since one can access both the final codebook vectors($codes) and the indices($unit.classif) of the matches.